# Getting jQuery to make item "selected"

Tags: jquery, css

I'm new to jQuery and looking to use it to keep the current menu item selected (as it looks in its hover state.)

My alert is firing, so the function seems to be starting.  When it's not commented out, the first statement, the one with the background-color of yellow works.  However, I can't seem to get the others to affect the menu.  The "selected" class doesn't seem to work.  In other words, the item I select in the menu is highlighted in yellow until the page changes, then it goes back to the default color.  I've tried many combinations of names for the .selected class, including just .selected.

**jQuery**

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.nav ul li').click(function() {
     alert("Go!");
   /*$('a', this).css("background-color","yellow");*/ 
    $('a', this).removeClass('selected');
    $('a', this).addClass('selected');  
  });
 });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="nav">
 <ul class="nav ul">
      <li class="selected"> <a href="index.php">HOME</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="about.php">ABOUT</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="k-5.php">K-5 PROJECTS<strong class="caret"></strong></a></li>
      <li> <a href="wishlist.php">WISH LIST</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="history.php">ART HISTORY</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="funlinks.php">FUN LINKS</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="contact.php">CONTACT</a> </li>     
 </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.nav ul li a:active {
   background-color: #FFB01C;
}

.nav ul li a:hover {
   background-color: #FFB01C;
}

.nav ul li .selected {
   background-color: #FFB01C;
}
```

Comment: When you click a link, the link is being followed and a new page is loaded. The style is being applied, but you lose it when a new page is loaded. Also, why would you remove the class and then immediately add it back with `$('a', this).removeClass('selected');
    $('a', this).addClass('selected');`?

Comment: I was trying to remove the prior selected item and apply it to the current one.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, however you page will just follow a normal link and load a new page. If you want the selection to "stick", you'll need to store the choice with a cookie.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure this works either use this code

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.nav ul li').click(function() {
     // the following code
     event.preventDefault();
     alert("Go!");
   /*$('a', this).css("background-color","yellow");*/ 
    $('a', this).removeClass('selected');
    $('a', this).addClass('selected');  
  });
 });
</script>
```

This will prevent the page from reloading. Or you should save which of the list item the user clicked on inside the cache or cookie and then upon that data change the style.

As already said by j08691 in comments, your change is being applied. But changes as soon as the new document (new page) is loaded in the browser. You are also mentioning this problem.

I have had made a few changes, here you can test them http://jsfiddle.net/gjsb398g/

Selecter in jQuery was changed to,

```
$('.nav li')
```

Since you're having the class applied to the list itself, so `$('.nav ul li')` was not working.

Second change has been described above. The page was loading, because you're having a hyperlink in your code. That has to move your document to the next one (load the next document), to prevent it from happening, I added the code. Now it works.

Comment: Might want to add some further detail to your answer. Why is the page reloading in the first place? What have you changed? Why does this fix the problem?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly, thanks sir, :) I have added the details now. :)

Comment: Thanks, but when I tried these changes in your jsfiddle, I can't tell if it's working because it's going to a login page.

Comment: Click on "About" in your jsfiddle.  It shows a blank page in that frame.

Comment: Where exactly? See, its working. Are you sure, you included the jQuery (Top left corner). Look at the image here, http://s23.postimg.org/8cagx26nf/Screenshot_730.png

Answer (score 0):

I Think This May Solve Your Requirement:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var loc = window.location;
    var pathName = location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    if(pathName=="")
    {
           $(".nav a").each(function(){                     
            var at=$(this).prop("href");
            if(at=="index.php")
            {
              $(this).parent().addClass("selected");                
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
            $(".nav a").each(function(){                        
            var at=$(this).prop("href");
            if(at==pathName)
            {
                $("li.selected").removeClass("selected");
                $(this).parent().addClass("selected");              
            }
         });
    }
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works except that now my links are not working.  The menu is functioning as I want, but the pages don't change.  Also, I added class="selected" to the home page anchor tag, so it will be highlighted when the index page loads.  Hopefully, that won't break anything.